# Why can't I reference to a table without variables in lua?

Tags: lua

The following code works as expected:

```lua
local t = {}
print(t[1])
```

The above will print nil.
How come the following code results in an error?

```lua
print({}[1])
```

What is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```lua
print(({"a", "b", "c"})[2]) -- "b"
```

Comment: Thank you! Why would I need brackets though?

Comment: @Cottient, the Lua syntax requires the braces. They make it an expression.

Comment: @Cottient Same thing works for `#` and strings, `#"hey"` won't work, but `#("hey")` returns 3.